# How to number math mode equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations

Is it possible to number equations written in math mode? I tried "\begin{equation}" around math mode, but it gives errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

    I can number the equations using ``begin{equation}''.
    \begin{equation}
        A = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} 
    \end{equation}

    But, how to number the equations in written using math mode?
    \[\mathrm{ \frac {P \models Q\stackrel{Y} {\rightleftharpoons} P \mbox{, } P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y} {P \models Q \rhd X} } \]

    \[\mathrm{ \frac {P \models Q, P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y} {Q \rhd X} } \]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's common to refer to displayed math material as “equation” even if it isn't a proper equation with an = sign.

Comment: Note that `\[...\]` **IS** math mode, just unnumbered math mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think (but I may be wrong) the `gather` environment may be what you're looking for. Note that display-style math is in effect inside a `gather` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

I can number a single-line equation using an \texttt{equation} environment.
\begin{equation}
   A = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} 
\end{equation}

I can number multi-line mathmode material with a \texttt{gather} environment.
\begin{gather}
    \mathrm{ \frac {P \models Q\stackrel{Y} \rightleftharpoons P ,\ 
       P \mathrel\lhd \langle X \rangle _Y} {P \models Q 
       \mathrel\rhd X} } \\[1ex] % "1ex" inserts a bit more vertical whitespace
    \mathrm{ \frac {P \models Q,\ 
       P \mathrel\lhd \langle X \rangle _Y} {Q \mathrel\rhd X} } 
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations for your 400K! It's not common knowledge, but the symbols `\lhd` and `\rhd` are *binary operations* (that is, `\mathbin`) rather than relations. Why? I really don't know, but it has been so since Lamport provided some additional symbols. In the case at hand, they seem to be used as relations, so something like `\mathrel\lhd` is needed (and a definition, of course, would be better).

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for the congrats! And many thanks for the suggestion to give `\lhd` and `\rhd status `math-rel`, which I've implemented gladly.